# Assemble API - Post render helpers - Marked.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, assemble, javascript-marked

I'm trying to build pages via Assemble API.

So far I can render the pages, as expected. However, I'm trying to apply Marked.js to the render process and am at a total loss as to how to add it.

My assemble script looks like:

```
const assemble = require("assemble");
const app = assemble();

app.create('page');
app.helper('hbs', require('handlebars'));
app.helper('markdown', require('helper-markdown'));
app.helper('log', function(val) {
    grunt.log.writeln(val);
});

app.task('load', function(cb) {
    app.data(...);
    app.partials(...);
    app.layout(...);
    app.pages(...);
    cb();
});

app.task('default', ['load'], function() {
    return app.toStrem('page')
    .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(app.renderFile('hbs'))
    .on('error', console.log)
    .pipe(extname())
    .pipe(app.dest(...))
});

app.build(['default'], function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    grunt.log.ok('done!');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify. Is your goal to process Markdown by any means? or do you have a specific reason to use Marked.js? It appears you have helper-markdown ready to go. You just need to use that helper in your layouts.

Comment: Marked is, sort of, working. However, it's not actually adding the tags it seems like it should to achieve code coloring.